# How to align card images in bootstrap 4.4 so that all the cards have equal width and height.?

Tags: css, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

So basically while making a simple website with Django and bootstrap 4.4 I came up with this issue. I was using 'cards' to add images of books in a grid format like in a bookstore web application. But the cards are not having equal dimensions. 
How to align card images in bootstrap 4.4 so that all the cards have equal width and height while keeping it responsive to the window size change.??

My problem in the image below. As you can see there the cards are not of same size when i add different images it changes its size as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTtz.jpg)

html

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            {% for book in object_list %}
            <div class="col s3">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{book.book_image}}" alt="">
                    <div class="card-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="text-white">{{book.name}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

and .css

```
body{
background: white url('images/webbg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Example image of what I actually want to have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkvK0.jpg)
I want exactly like what there is in the above picture with images loading from my database in a loop.(so not hardcoded image links embedded in html code)

Comment: What does it look like

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use `.card-deck` to achieve your goals

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-decks

If `.card-deck` won't work for you you can use the new [Grid Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#grid-cards). They allow you to select how many cards you want per row based on screen size. The don't automatically set themselves to being equal height however that is easily remedied by adding `.h-100` to the cards.

As an example, if you wanted 4 cards per row after the `xl` breakpoint, 3 after `md` and 2 on mobile you would write the following. Note there is some margin on the columns to give them some space as they wrap.

```
<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4">
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but deck wont work in my case. When I use deck all my book objects from database align in one row. What I actually want is a GRID form of placing them. I have added image of my problem that might help you guys. Waiting for a solution..

Comment: But I'm looping through the cards , like I have 8 books in my database im looping through all those 8 images. If I use the above code i'll get multiple copies of the same book. And if i try to put the loop in one column class the alignment will be disordered.

Comment: Why would you get multiple copies of the same book?